# Notice: Use of undefined constant for mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql

Having some trouble with some code i wrote 2 years ago,

Getting spammed with Notice: Use of undefined constant.

```
 <?php 
 include ("conectarbd.php");
 $sql = "SELECT * from stock WHERE tipo='microonda'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo "<table border=\"0\">";
 echo "<tr><td></td><td>".ID."</td><td>".Nombre."</td><td>".Modelo."</td></tr>";

 while($registro=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$registro[0].'</td><td>'.$registro[2].'</td><td>'.$registro[3].'</td><td><a href=profile.php?id='.$registro[0].'><img src="images/arrowbw.png" border="0"title="Profile"></a></td></tr>';

 }
 echo "</table>";
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID` `Nombre` and `Modelo` are treated as constants.

If they are meant to be strings (they are meant to be the column headings, right?), you want to put them inside quotes.

Comment: Oh, thanks heh, works like a charm now. Problem was that never really tried that for I presumed it was converting them into HTML.... whoops.